# Estou com dúvidas em como acessar um objeto instanciado em outra classe

Tags: java

Como posso imprimir o `ve.nome` criado na classe `TesteClientesPedidos`, por meio do método `mostrarDadosVendedor()`  da classe  Vendedor?

Classe TesteClientesPedidos:

```
public class TesteClientesPedidos{

    public static void cadastrarVendedor(){

        Vendedor ve = new Vendedor();

        System.out.println("CADASTRAR VENDEDOR\n");
        System.out.println("Nome:........:");
        ve.nome = lerVendedor.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Matricula:...:");       
        ve.matricula = lerVendedor.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Telefone:....:");
        ve.telefone = lerVendedor.next();

        System.out.println("Cidade:......:");
        ve.cidade = lerVendedor.next();

        System.out.println("E-mail:......:");
        ve.email = lerVendedor.next();

        System.out.println("Salário:.....:");
        ve.salario = lerVendedor.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Estado:......:");
        ve.estado = lerVendedor.next();

        try {
            System.out.println("Comissão:..:");
            ve.setComissao(leitura.nextDouble());

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Classe Vendedor:

```
public class Vendedor extends Funcionario{

   private double comissao;

@Override
public double calcularSalario() {
    return (this.salario + comissao);
}

public Vendedor(String nome, int matricula, String telefone, String email, String cidade, String estado,
        double salario, double comissao) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.telefone = telefone;
    this.email = email;
    this.cidade = cidade;
    this.estado = estado;
    this.salario = salario;
    this.comissao = comissao;

}

public void mostrarDadosVendedor() {
    System.out.println("DADOS DO VENDEDOR\n");
    System.out.println("Nome.....:" + nome + "\n");
    System.out.println("Matricula:" + matricula + "\n");
    System.out.println("Telefone.:" + telefone + "\n");
    System.out.println("Cidade...:" + cidade + "\n");
    System.out.println("Estado...:" + estado + "\n");
    System.out.println("Salario..:" + salario + "\n");
    System.out.println("Comissão.:" + comissao + "\n");
}

public double getComissao() {
    return comissao;
}

public void setComissao(double comissao) {
    this.comissao = comissao;
}
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60409/discussion-on-question-by-diogo-lopes-estou-com-duvidas-em-como-acessar-um-objet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você está fazendo uma confusão bem grande.

De qualquer forma, segundo o código da pergunta e o que foi entendido pelos comentários, a única coisa que falta é chamar o método `mostrarDadosVendedor()` no final do método `cadastrarVendedor()`.

```
// Aqui em cima fica toda a instanciação do objeto ve.nome = ...

ve.mostrarDadosVendedor();
```

---

```
public class TesteClientesPedidos{

    public static void cadastrarVendedor(){
        Vendedor ve = new Vendedor();

        System.out.println("CADASTRAR VENDEDOR\n");
        System.out.println("Nome:........:");
        ve.nome = lerVendedor.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Matricula:...:");       
        ve.matricula = lerVendedor.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Telefone:....:");
        ve.telefone = lerVendedor.next();

        System.out.println("Cidade:......:");
        ve.cidade = lerVendedor.next();

        System.out.println("E-mail:......:");
        ve.email = lerVendedor.next();

        System.out.println("Salário:.....:");
        ve.salario = lerVendedor.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Estado:......:");
        ve.estado = lerVendedor.next();

        try {
            System.out.println("Comissão:..:");
            ve.setComissao(leitura.nextDouble());

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        ve.mostrarDadosVendedor();
    }
}
```